# How to place circle and text in one line?

Tags: html, css

I have one stripe with white half-circle and two-lined text which is supposed to be next to circle and inside of the stripe. But it goes beyond the borders. If I apply **span** to these divs, nothing changes. How can I solve this?

[image]

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Loj4Lgkq/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="summarize">
  <div class="top-button">
    <span class="half-circle"></span>

    <div>First line</div>
    <div>Second line</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.summarize {
  background-color: #B7B7B7;
}

.top-button {
  height: 10vh;
}

.half-circle {
  background: white;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  border-radius: 00px 50px 50px 0px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Add  **float: left**  to your class **.half-circle** and resolve your issue. Cheers **:)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the answer to add `float: left;` certainly works, here is an option that uses flexbox.

The reason I prefer flexbox is because it can be easier aligned correctly.

```css
.summarize {
  background-color: #B7B7B7;
}

.top-button {
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.half-circle {
  background: #F0F0F0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  border-radius: 00px 50px 50px 0px;
  display: block;
}
.text {
  flex: 1;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.text span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="summarize">
  <div class="top-button">
    <div class="half-circle"></div>
    <div class="text">
      <span>line 1</span>
      <span>line 2</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just give `float: left;` to  `.half-circle`

```
.half-circle {
  background: white;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  border-radius: 00px 50px 50px 0px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  float: left;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Loj4Lgkq/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve what you want using a lot less markup would be to use an absolutely positioned [pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements), like so:

```css
div{
  background-color:#b7b7b7;
  height:10vh;
  padding-left:calc(20% + 10px);
  /* Left padding should be at least the same width as the pseudo-element - I added 10px to create some space between it and the content */
  position:relative;
}
div::before{
  background:#fff;
  border-radius:0 50px 50px 0;
  bottom:0;
  content:"";
  left:0;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  width:20%;
}
/** Add the following if you want to center the children vertically in the parent **/
div{
  align-content:center;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
p{
  flex:0 0 100%;
}
/** Presentational stuff for this Snippet **/
*{box-sizing:border-box;font-family:sans-serif;margin:0;padding:0;}
div{border:1px solid #999;margin:10px;}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>First line</p>
  <p>Second line</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you did not use flex properly nor in the right place.

If you make your circle and a container holding the text sibblings, it will easily work:

```css
.summarize {
  background-color: #B7B7B7;
}
.top-button {
  height:3em;/* vh might not be the best idea ... */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.half-circle {
  background: white;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  border-radius: 00px 50px 50px 0px;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="summarize">
  <div class="top-button">
    <span class="half-circle"></span>
    <div>
      <p>
        First line</p>
      <p>
        Second line</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Loj4Lgkq/4/

increase container height ?

```css
.summarize {
  background-color: #B7B7B7;
}
.top-button {
  height:10em;/* vh might not be the best idea ... */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.half-circle {
  background: white;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  border-radius: 00px 50px 50px 0px;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="summarize">
  <div class="top-button">
    <span class="half-circle"></span>
    <div>
      <p>
        First line</p>
      <p>
        Second line</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How can I align my text vertically in case if stripe height would be taller than  text height.

Comment: @BillyLogan `align-items:center` already does the job here https://jsfiddle.net/Loj4Lgkq/5/

Answer (score 0):

That will work:

```css
.summarize {
  background-color: #B7B7B7;
}
.top-button {
  height: 10vh;
}
.half-circle {
  background: white;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  border-radius: 00px 50px 50px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="summarize">
  <div class="top-button">
    <span class="half-circle"></span>

    <span>First line</span>
    <span>Second line</span>
  </div>
</div>
```